# Mediarouter icon not displayed while relaunching the activity

Tags: android, chromecast

I am working on integrating `Google Chromecast` in one of my `Android` application.I am using `MediaRouteButton` in my custom layout with my `PlayerActivity` extending `FragmentActivity`.

**Scenario 1:**

I start `PlayerActivity`, the `chromecast` icon is displayed, the `chromecast` device is detected , I select it and cast the video on TV.

Then **I disconnect** the device from app, go back to previous activity on backpress. Again I launch `PlayerActivity` and again same sequence of events is observed. **This is fine**.

However

**Scenario 2:**

I start `PlayerActivity`, the chromecast device is detected , I select it and cast the video. This time **I don't disconnect** the device from app,go back to previous activity on backpress. Again I launch `PlayerActivity` but this time the chromecast icon is not displayed.

What could be the reason for such behaviour? Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

I referred to [CastButton](https://github.com/googlecast/MediaRouter-Cast-Button-android) example, and I observed same behaviour when I checked it for `MediaRouterButtonActivity.java` which also extends FragmentActivity. However when I tried same sequence with `MediaRouterActionBarButtonActivity.java` which extends `ActionBarActivity`, it worked fine.

UPDATE:

I am using following

```
private class MyMediaRouterCallback extends MediaRouter.Callback {

        @Override
        public void onRouteAdded(MediaRouter router, RouteInfo route) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onRouteAdded");
            if (++mRouteCount == 1) {
                // Show the button when a device is discovered.
                mMediaRouteButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRouteRemoved(MediaRouter router, RouteInfo route) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onRouteRemoved");
            if (--mRouteCount == 0) {
                // Hide the button if there are no devices discovered.
                mMediaRouteButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRouteSelected(MediaRouter router, RouteInfo info) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onRouteSelected");
            // Handle route selection.
            mSelectedDevice = CastDevice.getFromBundle(info.getExtras());           
        }

        @Override
        public void onRouteUnselected(MediaRouter router, RouteInfo info) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onRouteUnselected: info=" + info);
            mSelectedDevice = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: MediaRouteButton's visibility is handled by the application so you need to tell us about how you are trying to handle that and what logic/code you are using for that purpose.

Comment: Your logic for making the cast button visible or not is triggered when a new route is added/removed. Lets say a route is discovered in Activity A. Then you go to Activity B; and in between, no new route is added or removed. As a result, the above logic is not triggered in Activity B so the cast button remains invisible. A better approach is to have this logic in, say, your Application instance and keep track of the current state there and have each activity ask the application instance if they should make the cast button visible or not upon their startup. they should also listen for changes.

Comment: Thnx Ali, I shall definitely try it.

Comment: Ali its working. Thanx for your suggestion. If you could post your comment as answer, I would accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic for making the cast button visible or not is triggered when a new route is added/removed. Lets say a route is discovered in Activity A. Then you go to Activity B; and in between, no new route is added or removed. As a result, the above logic is not triggered in Activity B so the cast button remains invisible. A better approach is to have this logic in, say, your Application instance and keep track of the current state there and have each activity ask the application instance if they should make the cast button visible or not upon their startup. they should also listen for changes.

Comment: Thank you, Ali for your answer.